# C++ WSAEFAULT error sending integer

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am trying to send an integer over the internet. The problem is not bid-endian related, as the problem also arises when i send the integer to myself with 127.0.0.1 . This is the code:

```
int res = send(Socket, (char*)refresh, sizeof(refresh), 0);
```

Refresh is usually 100. res is -1, and calling WsaGetLastError returns 10014, *WSAEFAULT*.
From what I understood this means the size I've specified is different from the size of the buffer. How can the size of refresh be different from sizeof(refresh)?
On the other side:

```
int dim = recv(Socket, (char*)&refresh, sizeof (refresh), MSG_WAITALL);
```

*dim* is 4, wich is right, but if I check refresh it's still 0. 
Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSAEFAULT` means the combination of `buf` and `len` parameter values working together does not represent a valid memory block within the calling process's address space.

`(char*)refresh` passes the **value** of the integer interpreted as a memory address, which is the wrong thing to do.

`(char*)&refresh` passes the **address** of the integer, which is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being a noob. I'll mark as right answer as soon as i can.